# How to apply De-Morgan's Law to a string of Boolean expression in Python?

Tags: python, string, boolean, boolean-logic, boolean-expression

I have written a program which takes a Boolean expression as string input and gives the function's truth table. It is working well for all types of expressions except those which involve whole complements, i.e. complements of some sub-expression (not a variable). [e.g. `A'(BC+D)` gives no problem but `A(BC+D)'` does].

I am not opting for Pythonic logical expressions (e.g. `not(a+b)` instead of `(a+b)'`), since the expressions are taken as user input and user is assumed to be a non-programmer.

Suppose I have a string like `((ab'+cd)'+cd'+ab)'`. Applying De Morgan's law repeatedly, I must get an expression like:

`(ab'+cd)(c'+d)(a'+b')`

Similarly, `(a'b+ab')c'+(a'b+ab')'c` must become `(a'b+ab')c+(ab+a'b')c`.

How can this be done in Python?

The code I have written so far is-

```
f=raw_input("enter the Boolean expression:")
fin=f
alpha=list(set([i for i in f if i in [chr(64+n) for n in range(27)]]))
alpha.sort()

truth=[bin(n).replace("0b","").rjust(int(len(alpha)),"0") for n in range(0,2**(len(alpha)))]

def change(string,old,new):
    pos=string.index(old)
    return string[:pos]+new+string[pos+1:]

out=[]
for i in range(len(truth)):
    for elem in f:
        if elem in alpha:
            if (f.index(elem))+1<len(f) and f[(f.index(elem))+1]=="'":
                f=change(f,elem,str(abs(int(truth[i][alpha.index(elem)])-1)))
            else:
                f=change(f,elem,truth[i][alpha.index(elem)])
    out.append(f)
    f=fin

out=[elem.replace("'","") for elem in out]
out=['+'.join('*'.join(x) for x in s.split('+')) for s in out]

m=f.count("(")

for k in range(m):
    for string in out:
        for i in range(len(string)):
            if string[i]=="(" and string[i+1]=="*":
                out[out.index(string)]=string[:i+1]+""+string[i+2:]
                break

for k in range(m):
    for string in out:
        for i in range(len(string)):
            if string[i]==")" and string[i-1]=="*":
                out[out.index(string)]=string[:i-1]+""+string[i:]
                break

out=[int(eval(elem)) for elem in out]
out=[int(elem/float(abs(elem))) if elem>=1 else 0 for elem in out]
print "Output values of the truth table:",out

print "--"*(7*len(alpha)+len(f)+2)
for elem in alpha:
    print elem,"\t",
print "  Y=",f
print "--"*(7*len(alpha)+len(f)+2)
for elem in truth:
    for i in range(len(elem)):
        tr=elem[i].split()
        for j in tr:
            print j,"\t",
    print "  "*(len(f)/2),out[truth.index(elem)],"\n"
```

This was written in Python 2.7,small tweaks maybe necessary for Python 3.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Do you actually need to implement De Morgan's law? Or to fix your algorithm to make it work well with sub-expressions? If your input is an expression as string and as the result you get the truth table, I guess fixing your algorithm would be easier than De Morgan's law implementation.

Comment: Honestly, this question is way too broad. You need to write a parser, and then write something like a mini CAS (computer algebra system) that deals only with boolean logic. Or maybe, you can just use `sympy`, a full-fledged CAS. But you will still probably have to write some sort of parser.

Comment: @ParthasarathySubburaj Added the code.

Comment: @Fomalhaut How can i fix the algorithm?I have added the code,How can i modify that?

Answer (score 0):

I would do your task with regular expressions. Here is full code of the algorithm:

```
import re
import itertools


def get_variables(expr):
    return sorted(set(re.findall(r'[a-z]', expr)))


def perform_and(expr):
    """
    ab -> (a and b)
    (...)(...) -> (...) and (...)
    """
    expr = re.sub(r"([a-z]\'?)\s*([a-z]\'?)", r"(\1 and \2)", expr)
    expr = re.sub(r"([a-z]\'?)\s*(\()", r"(\1 and \2", expr)
    expr = re.sub(r"(\)\')\s*([a-z]\'?)", r"\1 and \2)", expr)
    expr = re.sub(r"(\)\')\s*(\()", r"\1 and \2", expr)
    return expr


def perform_or(expr):
    """
    ... + ... -> ... or ...
    """
    return re.sub(r"\+", " or ", expr)


def perform_not(expr):
    """
    a' -> not a
    (...)' -> not (...)
    """
    # Replacing brackets from () to {} (replacing back will be in the while-loop)
    expr = expr.replace("(", "{")
    expr = expr.replace(")", "}")

    # Adding 'not' to separate variables
    expr = re.sub(r"([a-z])\s*\'", r"not \1", expr)

    # Loop until expr stops changing
    while True:
        # Adding 'not' to expressions in {}-brackets without {}-brackets inside
        expr_new = re.sub(r"\{([^\{\}]+)\}\s*\'", r"not (\1)", expr)

        # Replacing brackets back from {} to ()
        expr_new = re.sub(r"\{([^\{\}]+)\}(\s*[^\'])", r"(\1)\2", expr_new)

        # Leaving the loop if nothing changed
        if expr == expr_new:
            break
        else:
            expr = expr_new

    # Replacing back
    expr = expr.replace("{", "(")
    expr = expr.replace("}", ")")

    return expr


def to_pythonic(expr):
    expr = perform_and(expr)
    expr = perform_or(expr)
    expr = perform_not(expr)
    expr = re.sub(r'\s+', ' ', expr)  # reducing multiple spaces (not necesary)
    return expr


def build_truth_table(pythonic_expr, variables):
    print(" ".join(variables), "->", "result")
    for values in itertools.product([0, 1], repeat=len(variables)):
        dct = dict(zip(variables, values))
        result = int(eval(pythonic_expr, dct))
        print(" ".join(map(str, values)), "->", result)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    expr = "((ab'+cd)'+cd'+ab)'"

    pythonic_expr = to_pythonic(expr)
    variables = get_variables(expr)
    build_truth_table(pythonic_expr, variables)
```

The main idea is to pythonize your expression with the replacements `empty -> and`, `+ -> or`, `' -> not`, keeping brackets correctly. After that I iterate all possible values for the variables given and run `eval` for the pythonized expression to calculate the results.